# Octave error: element undefined in return list

Tags: octave

I am writing the following octave code:

```
function p = predict(Theta1, Theta2, X)
m = size(X, 1);
num_labels = size(Theta2, 1);
global a=zeros(size(Theta2, 2), m);
global delta=zeros(m, 1);

p = zeros(size(X, 1), 1);

X=[ones(size(X,1),1) X];
a=sigmoid(Theta1*X');
a=[ones(1,size(X,1));a];
[delta p]=max(sigmoid(Theta2*a))';
```

It gives me the error: "element number 2 undefined in return list".
The error occurs when I use delta in the last line to store max values.
I have searched a lot but couldn't find any relevant answer.

Comment: Please please please create a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
[delta p] = max( sigmoid( Theta2*a ) )'; # transpose operator over the result
```

is equivalent to

```
[delta p] = transpose( max( sigmoid( Theta2*a ) ); # transpose function over the result
```

which means you are trying to get a "two-output" result out of this transpose operation, which fails, since the transpose function only returns one output, therefore octave is informing you that it cannot find a second output in the 'results' list.

Presumably you either meant to do something along the lines of:

```
[delta p] = max( sigmoid( Theta2*a )' );
```

and misplaced the transpose operator, or you actually *did* want to obtain the maxima and their indices as a column vector, in which case you need to do this in two steps, i.e.

```
[delta p] = max( sigmoid( Theta2*a ) );
ColVector = [delta p]';
```

PS. Incidentally, you should use `.'` instead of `'` as the transpose operator. `'` is not the transpose operator, it's the "conjugate transpose" one.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it using this
[delta p]=max(sigmoid(Theta2*a)',[],2);
I thought the error was due to max function somehow. But your explanation cleared my confusion.